# How to declare a new delegate that differ from function signature?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

```
delegate void EmptyBody(ref int first );
delegate void AnotherEmptyBody(int first );
delegate void AnotherEmptyBody1(int first, int second);

public void aaa(params object[] pars)
{
    DoSpecifiedProcessing();

    pars[0] = 11;
}

public bool OnInIt()
{
    int b = 0;

    b = 44;
    var n = new EmptyBody(aaa);
    n(ref b);
    //b variable must be 11


    b = 44;
    var x = new AnotherEmptyBody(aaa);
    x(b);
    //b shoudn't be changed in this call, so it should be 44
}
```

I'm trying to have a generic function like `aaa` which is defined in code.
The first call should change `b` because it's passed as by-ref but the second call shouldn't change `b` because it's passed as by-val.

Comment: Your method signature doesn't match the signature for your delegates, which is a requirement. Can you alter aaa's argument?

Comment: @ChrisHardie I can alter `aaa` arguments but I need a generic function that works on any number of arguments. There might be more than 100 delegates which every of them has a different signature!

Comment: The entire point of delegates is to make this impossible, type safety is a big deal.  No point in declaring 100 delegate types when you can use the Action<> and Func<> generic delegate types.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using this to have parameter name on coding-time.. I need VS popup that tell me what are my parameters, in this example could be `ref int first`. Also another reason is that I need this for a obfuscation type...

Comment: You cannot supply a method with a `params` argument to a delegate with individual arguments, since the `params` argument is always an array and has to be treated like one in the method's body.

Comment: You are trying to defeat the whole purpose of delegates. This is not something it is intended to do.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. You could write a `aaa` method that would accommodate all possibilities of its use and write adapter methods that would conform to the signature of the intended delegate. Maybe if you showed some real life scenarios where you intend to use this we could offer some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with delegates because the parameters of the delegates and `aaa` don't match.
You can do something like this instead (create method adapters `aaaRefInt` and `aaaInt`):

```
public void aaaRefInt(ref int first)
{
    object[] Args = new object[]{first};        
    aaa(Args);
    first = (int)Args[0];
}

public void aaaInt(int first)
{
    aaa(new object[]{first});
}

var n = new EmptyBody(aaaRefInt);
n(ref b);

var x = new AnotherEmptyBody(aaaInt);
x(b);
```